# changing activity(context) affect on access permision to received uri?

Tags: android, uri, file-descriptor

I'm trying to receive file from 'share menu' outside of my application and then process on it. I receive `Uri` and convert it to `fileDescriptor`, put it in static variable and then use that variable in another activity. The problem is at first activity, every thing works well (like getting thumbnail with `MetaDataRetriever`) but in the next activity and with same method it gives error `java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000`. Same happens if I use `URI` directly. I know I can do all on same activity, but prefer to do it on separated activities.

```
public static Bitmap videoThumbMini(FileDescriptor descriptor) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        try {
            retriever.setDataSource(descriptor);
            bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(1000);
            if (bitmap == null)
                return null;
            float ratio = 1;
            if (bitmap.getHeight() > 300)
                ratio = bitmap.getHeight() / 300f;
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) (bitmap.getWidth() / ratio), 200, false);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Logger.log(e.getMessage() + " ERR3", false, e);
        } finally {
            try {
                retriever.release();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.log(e.getMessage() + " ERR4", false, e);
            }
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for who come later, this makes it work properly:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/grant-uri-permission-element

this method should run in your first activity and allow whole your app ti use that uri.

```
grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

set packagename as same as your app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).